# C++ TestMate: no hierarchical view, no refresh

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, ctest

I use C++ TestMate (V4.4.2) with CMakeTools (1.14.31) in VS Code and with GoogleTest.

I can compile and run tests, but two things surprise:

- In the VS Code test view, all test cases are only shown as list, but not in a hierarchy as seen in several examples in the web.
- Clicking on the TestMate widgets, the test are neither re-built, nor will the results be updated (red/green); even when the tests were freshly run with CTest before. According to the description, TestMate widgets should do that job, shouldn't they?

So it that a configuration issue?

Example: two of the tests are named:

```
TEST( sequencialOfSerialNumber, SerialNumberType ) { ...

TEST( sequencialOfSerialNumber, SerialNumberType2 )
```

so I expected that they would at least appear under a node `sequencialOfSerialNumber` or `SerialNumberType.exe` but they don't.

The screenshot shows that one test case did obviously (correctly) fail with CTest, but "Run Test" did not run them again nor update TestMate's view.

[image]